# Checking if a window is already opened MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have searched and I found this:

```
public static bool IsWindowOpen<T>(string name = "") where T : Window
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any()
                : Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any(w => w.Name.Equals(name));
        }
```

It doesn't seem to work though. I can still open multiple window's. My current understand is that the name of the "Window" is the name of XAML file or that would be the title? I have tried both and I can still open th window multiple times.

I'm trying to open the window like this (I realize that this may not be the best way to open a window in MVVM):

```
    public void OpenForm()
    {

        var taskViewModel = new HistoryEmpViewModel(Convert.ToInt32(SelectedEmploye.MatEmp));
        EmpHistory X = new EmpHistory(taskViewModel);
        if (IsWindowOpen<Window>("EmpHistory"))
            return;
        X.Show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension method checks Name property, but EmpHistory windows which are opened don't have any.

Assign a Name:

```
public void OpenForm()
{
    if (IsWindowOpen<Window>("EmpHistory"))
        return;
    var taskViewModel = new HistoryEmpViewModel(Convert.ToInt32(SelectedEmploye.MatEmp));
    EmpHistory X = new EmpHistory(taskViewModel);
    X.Name = "EmpHistory";
    X.Show();
}
```

Or test by concrete type:

```
public void OpenForm()
{
    if (IsWindowOpen<EmpHistory>())
        return;
    var taskViewModel = new HistoryEmpViewModel(Convert.ToInt32(SelectedEmploye.MatEmp));
    EmpHistory X = new EmpHistory(taskViewModel);
    X.Show();
}
```

note that is better verify condition before creating window instance